# Kill Overlapping Threads from Intent in Android mp3 app

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am having a problem (I think) with overlapping threads playing music in my android mp3 player. I have a class SongList.java that lists and plays music when an item is clicked and a ArtistList.java that intents SongList to play songs by that specific artist. Two or more songs will play at the same time if they are not in the same activity.

How do I tell my playSong method to stop all threads but the most recent one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have just one single Thread or service doing playback.
`SongList` and `ArtistList` should not start a new service. Rather you should have a `PlaybackService` you can pass a `SongList` or `ArtistList` as parameter / argument. If doing so, you should just have one single Thread doing playback and never run into that kind of trouble.

Have a look here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices

They implement a `Service` that uses the build in `MediaPlayer` for audio playback. Next you can bind your `MusicPlaybackService` to an activity.

Here is an introduction:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

You can specify methods that the activity can invoke on your service with the help of `Binder`. So you could provide a method like `playSongs(SongList songs)` or `playArtists(ArtistList list)` that could be invoked by the activity (i.e. by clicking on a certain button). Since the service runs the playback (by using `MediaPlayer`) the service is responsible for Threading and playback. So if you call `playSongs(SongList songs)` of the service, the Service should stop `MediaPlayer` and restart `MediaPlayer` with the desired music file (provided by `SongList`). With this approach your `MusicPlaybackService` manages the playback and guarantees that only one music file is played simultaneously.

Comment: I understand this conceptually but not how to implement it. Currently SongList has an instance of my mp3Player. I would prefer each class to have a reference to the same mp3Player so I could pass an argument. But since all of these classes have been created from Intent, I don't know how to navigate between the classes without creating an Intent.

Comment: Likely the actual playback should be accomplished via a singleton